# HTTP Error 404.0 Not Found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, stored-procedure, controller, model-view-controller

Buen dia compañeros tengo este codigo del contrlador y la vista en asp.net mvc pero al dar clic en edit me sale este error ya verifique haber creado la vista, creo que no identifica por id pero en mi codigo en el controlador lo puse para que fuera por id.

> HTTP Error 404.0 Not Found Se ha quitado el recurso que esta buscando,
>   se le ha cambiado el nombre o no esta disponible en estos momentos
>
> Requested URL:localhost:xxx/prueba/edit/3

**código en el controlador**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using proyecto.Models;

namespace proyecto.Controllers
{
    public class testController : Controller
    {
        private TestStatusyEntities db = new TestStatusyEntities();
        // GET: test
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.testmostrar().ToList());
        }

        // GET: test/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(double id)
        {
            return View();
        }

        // GET: test/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: test/Create
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add insert logic here

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

public Action Result Edit(double id)
    {
        prueba usr = db.selectid(id).First();
        return View(usr);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public Action Result Edit(double id, FormCollection collection)
    {
        try
        {
            prueba usr = db.selectid(id).First();
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.spactualizar(id, collection["encargado"],collection["estado"],collection["material"]);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
```

**Vista**

```
    @model proyecto.Models.prueba
    @{
        ViewBag.Title ="Edit";
    }

    <h2>Edit</h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <fieldset>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.encargado)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.encargado)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.estado)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.estado)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.material)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.material)
            </div>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="guardar"/>
            </p>

        </fieldset>
    }

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("regresar", "Index")
</div>
```

Comment: Hola, puedes mostrar el codigo completo del controller? El nombre de la clase al menos. Tambien5 puedes mostramos cómo tienes definido la tabla de rutas?

Comment: hola compañero ya puse el codigo de mi controller completo, cual es la tabla de rutas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La clase es `testController` y la URL que te está dando el error es `/prueba/edit/3`; lo que necesitas en cambiar en la dirección ese "`prueba`" por el nombre de tu controlador **sin el sufijo `Controller`**, en este caso "`test`":

> localhost:xxx/test/edit/3

Lo único que tienes que hacer es cambiar la dirección en cada enlace desde donde intentas llegar, que en tu caso debe ser en tu vista `Index` de la carpeta `/Views/test`.

Answer (score 1):

Aclaraciones:

¿Estás seguro que compila "Action Result" ? Debería ser una sola palabra.

Del siguiente código, tienes una coma que genera otro problema.

```
public Action Result Edit(double id,)
{
    prueba usr = db.selectid(id).First();
    return View(usr);
}
```

Agrega tu rutas que tienes definidas en el Global.asax, algo así:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
  routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
}
```

Comment: no me sale error en esa parte compañero la coma no se donde salio pero no esta en el codigo, Compañero en que parte del global.asax va   
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
    }

Answer (score 1):

La ruta debería ser

> localhost:xxx/test/edit/3

Por defecto se toma el nombre de la clase quitando el sufijo de Controller

Comment: Compañero con eso quiere decir   que tengo que cambiar esto?,@model proyecto.Models.prueba

Comment: Pues depende de qué modelo le debes pasar a la vista. En tu código además no veo que pases ningún modelo.

Comment: a que te refieres con pasar un modelo compañero pense que esto era @model proyecto.Models.prueba

Comment: Vale, perdona. Si que en principio lo estás pasando.  `prueba usr = db.selectid(id).First();  return View(usr);`